# Prevent isNaN implicit conversion to number

Tags: javascript, validation, numbers

I'm learning some JavaScript and ran into a quirk and was wondering if anyone knew a way to override this behavior. I'd like to be able to test if a value passed to a function is a *real* number, and I thought using `===` for the `isNaN()` check would take care of that, but it doesn't.

Example function:

```
var foodDemand = function(food) {
    if (isNaN(food) === false) {
        console.log("I can't eat " + food + " because it's a number");
    } else {
        console.log("I want to eat " + food);
    }
};
```

And I test with this:

```
// behaves as expected
foodDemand("steak");
foodDemand(999999999);
foodDemand(0.0000001337);
foodDemand([1]);
foodDemand(undefined);
foodDemand(NaN);
foodDemand({});
// converts non-number to a number
foodDemand("42");
foodDemand("");
foodDemand(null);
foodDemand([]);
foodDemand("\n");
```

Output *(italics represent unexpected results)*:

> ```
> I want to eat steak
> I can't eat 999999999 because it's a number
> I can't eat 1.337e-7 because it's a number
> I can't eat 1 because it's a number
> I want to eat undefined
> I want to eat NaN
> I want to eat [object Object]
> I can't eat 42 because it's a number
> I can't eat  because it's a number
> I can't eat null because it's a number
> I can't eat  because it's a number
> I can't eat 
>  because it's a number
> ```

Is there any way to make `isNaN()` more strict?

Comment: Some browsers support `Number.isNaN()`, which does not perform the type conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isNaN`'s purpose is not really to test if something is litterally not a number, but to test if something is the number NaN (since `NaN===NaN` returns false in JavaScript you can't use equality).

You should use `typeof` instead, and then isNaN:

```
if((typeof food)==="number" && !isNaN(food))
```

Why, you may ask, is `NaN` not equal to `NaN` ?? Is that one more of JavaScript's infamous quirks?

Turns out there is a good reason for this behavior. Mathematical operations that can't return a real result, not even Infinity, will not complain and throw an error. They just return NaN. For example, 0/0, sqrt(-1), acos(2). Wouldn't it be weird to have `Math.sqrt(-1) === 0/0`? So NaN is not equal to even itself. And therefore, a primitive like `isNaN` is needed in case you actually want to check if a value *is NaN*.

Comment: Wow that's weird. Makes sense though the way you explained it!

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript :) The idea behind the NaN inequality is that several mathematical operations return NaN, and it wouldn't make sense if 0/0 were equal to sqrt(-1), for example. So the language needs something else to check for NaN.

Comment: You should put that in your answer, for the next person left scratching their head about `isNaN` :)

Answer (score 4):

isNaN() is not checking if something is not a number type, its literally checking if something is the value "NaN", as you've found. `typeof` is your friend here.

`((typeof foo) === 'number') && !isNaN(foo)` should work for what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify why this solution is not what you'd want to use for checking the type of the value passed to you?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `isNaN` function is to check if a value is exactly equal to the built-in `NaN` constant value. It shouldn't be used to check if something is a number or not, even if that might seem counter-intuitive. It only exists because `NaN === NaN` returns false, so it's the only way to check if a function involving numbers failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (typeof food == "number") {
    console.log("I can't eat " + food + " because it's a number");
} else {
    console.log("I want to eat " + food);
}
```